# How to have a single transaction that enables a custom program to verify two partial offline signers?

Tags: transactions, signature, signing, transaction-instructions

I need a single transaction that allows a custom program to verify that two signers are who they say they are:

1. signer1: create, sign, serialize transaction and send to signer2.
2. signer2: deserialize, sign and send to custom program.
3. custom program: verify both signers

How can signer2 be sure that signer1 hasn't put a malicious instruction in the transaction?

If individual instructions could be signed, that could solve the problem.
The only solution I can think of here is:

1. signer1: create, sign transaction with durable nonce and send the signature to signer2.
2. signer2: create, sign its own separate identical transaction and add signer1's signature.